# What is the point with the tag [bestestes]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

[Peter Turner](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1973/peter-turner) is retagging a hole lot of questions and adding the tag [`[bestestes]`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bestestes). I can't understand the meaning of the tag or how it is useful.

What's the point of the tag `[bestestes]`? and is it useful?

Comment: Well, that's another blip in programmers.se lore. I wonder why the moderators and power users don't use the tools they have to make the site a better place.  Could have done the synonym thing on bestestes and created a better title and had everything looking just swell by Monday.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This tag is not useful.  "Recommendations" and "Favorites" is covered by voting on questions/answers and the star.  "Best" is relative and there are tools in place to better facilitate what I think Peter is trying to accomplish.

Rather than retagging, a better way to point out "best of breed" questions is to create a blog post or something outside the site which points to your "top X questions and answers on [some subject]" or something like that.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with that, bestestes isn't even a word so I didn't think it would endure.  I just wanted a tag that people who loathe the idea of having "Best Of" posted all over the site could unilaterally ignore them.  It doesn't seem right to unilaterally close them - which has had it's backlash, it takes advantage of the clear majority of users who take the time to answer them and don't care about the politics and aim of the site.  That being said, it doesn't make sense to subject the upper crust users to anything they deem impertinent, since they're keeping the site going.

Comment: @Peter Turner I get it...you were trying to enable a mechanism for filtering a certain kind of question, right?  "What's the best ____" type questions?  It's an interesting taxonomic strategy but I'm afraid of taking it to the logical conclusion which is to have tons of meta-tags.

Comment: Ok. But what does it mean!?

Answer (score -8):

Yeah, I'm not trying to get them closed or anything.  I'm just making up something that maybe we can merge into recommendations or favorites or just leave alone so that some semblance of what I believe to be the original purpose of this website can be preserved.  People who like the "bestestes" (or "worstestes") tag can have it in their list, people who would just close'em on principle can just ignore them.

I'm all done now, I just searched for "best" got to page 12 and they kind of fizzled out.

I think we can merge tags into some sort of better synonym.  There obviously is a better (real) word than bestestes.  I just wanted something that'd stick out. And as I'm a bum not a moderator or a high-rep-y-ite and don't believe in closation without representation I'm doing what I can within my limited powers, feel free to join in!

Comment: It reads to me as "best testes". Seriously.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a vas defrens between what you saw and what I was trying to do!

Comment: Which ones are the best testes and the worst testes? How do you distinguish one from the other one?